# Installing Windows 10 "We couldn't create a new partition."

Tags: windows

i'm trying to install the Windows 10 test build on my laptop dual-booted with Windows 7. I had Windows 8 dual booted previously, but deleted it to make space for 10. Upon trying to create a new partition for Windows 10, I get the following message:
"We couldn't create a new partion. [Error: 0x984b3f50]."
Google turned up nothing, and i'm not quite sure what to do. Anyone know what's causing it?

Edit: Almost forgot, it's also saying windows can't be installed on this drive, and giving me the popup:
"Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table.  On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks."

I know how to fix THIS one, but I have an abhorrent amount of important personal files and code and such on my machine, and it would take QUITE a while to back it all up, (like 20 hours) but would just backing it up and wiping the disc be the best option at this point?

Answer (score 21):

I have found a fairly simple solution. (This if for people who are installing via USB)

1. Go into your bios and set the HDD that you want to install as the very first boot device. Save and restart.
2. Manually access your boot loader when bios starts. From here select your USB to boot with.
3. Proceed normally with the install.

It seems that the partition manager in the windows installation gets confused when when it detects a USB that has a higher boot priority then the HDD you're installing on. It thinks the USB is the system partition. By setting the HDD to the first booting device, it no longer looks at the USB as a boot device.

This would also explain why the remove USB key while creating the partitions work. By removing the USB, it no longer sees it and so it skips to the next bootable device to look for the windows system partition. When it doesn't find one, it will now device to create it on its own.

Hope this helps some of you. It took a few hours of sleep out of mine.

Comment: This is precisely it. Step 2 is essential, it still didn't work for me when I let the PC auto-boot from the USB drive. Gotta hammer F12 and choose it manually.

Comment: Non of the above works for me... I got a laptop with a single HDD and I am installing Win 10 from a USB. It always display this message to me.

Is there are any solution for this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @Ahmed_Eissa Sorry, I haven't tried with a laptop. Some laptops have hidden recovery partitions, maybe that's what hindering.

Comment: TX man. MS Windows... still crap after all these years.

Comment: @J.B.Lai I used this solution and it worked, after 4-5 hours of looking for a way to fix this. Thank you very much!

Comment: still works, many years later.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual hard drive on the Win7 partition and install Windows into this VHD.
Sorry for the limited answer, but am on mobile.
Google will bring up plenty of guides how to install Windows into VHD.

After installation you will have the normal Windows boot menu to chose which OS to boot.

I did above to test Win10 on my machine next to Win7.

Additional advantage: keep a copy of the vhd to be able to revert to a fresh install after a test. Or boot it into hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have the ISO of the OS, use Rufus Tool choose the ISO image, browse and select the OS ISO, then choose partition scheme as MBR Partition for UEFI Computer. Flash, then restart in any way HDD first (then select manually USB) or set USB first.

Go to windows installation and create partition. Done.

2) Alternative solution,

Log on to Windows 8, use a partition tool, convert your disk to GPT and use the same pen drive (GPT Partition scheme) flashed bootable USB.

I hope you get it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Changing the boot priority option from BIOS did not help for me. Another solution might be:

- To boot the PC with a Linux live USB with basic utilities installed (I am using an Archlinux Live USB for these purposes)
- In order not to interfere with the file system of the USB, check the device (/dev/sdX) of the USB from `df -h` and check the device letter of the HDD/SSD from `ls /dev/sd*`. The device is probably /dev/sda
- Check the existing partitions' start end positions with `sudo parted /dev/sdX print` where X is the device letter
- Enter into parted prompt with `sudo parted /dev/sdX`
- Create a new partition using `mkpart primary ntfs 1050MB 100%` in case the last partition ends at 1050MB, and the new partition is supposed to occupy the rest of the drive. Quit parted with `quit`
- Run `sudo mkfs -t ntfs /dev/sdXY` where X is the letter of the device and Y is the number of partition to be formatted.

After you boot with Windows installation medium, the new ntfs partition should be recognized.

If the real problem is that the volume has an MBS partition table while it should have a GPT one, the first command after entering the parted prompt will be `mklabel GPT`. **Note that this will erase the whole disk**. Then you can create partitions from parted command or leave this task to Windows installation medium.

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions:

1. You don't mind using older technology (BIOS).
2. Your main concern is that you would like to not backup everything and rebuild your system from scratch.

Go to the 'BIOS setup' and change the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy. (You may need to disable Secure Boot and EFI Option ROMs, depending on your BIOS version.) Now boot using the installation medium (CD/DVD/USB).

For some background info regarding UEFI, see [this](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) excellent website.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer -- please leave a comment with what can be improved.